# Setting up phone for parent, want picture to call a phone number

Tags: ios

I'm trying to understand how to setup a picture of myself for my father's iPhone so he can press on the picture of me (on his home screen) and it will call me.

I found this site callmeicons.com (I haven't been to it) from this video https://www.google.com/search?q=how+do+I+make+a+picture+dial+a+number%3F+iphone&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS947US947&oq=how+do+I+make+a+picture+dial+a+number%3F++iphone&aqs=chrome..69i57.13835j0j15&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#kpvalbx=_sEy3YoJHxqzk2g_M0ofIBg17

which explains how to set this up, but I don't understand how it works and it seems to be making calls through that site which I don't want to do.

**Is there a way to on an iPhone setup a picture on the home screen to call a phone number.**

Comment: *"I haven't been to it"* well, why not? btw, the google search will show different results for everybody who clicks the link.

Comment: Or perhaps you are asking the wrong question? I think a shortcut could do this... https://www.howtogeek.com/736926/how-to-add-a-contact-to-the-home-screen-on-iphone/

Comment: @SteveChambers That's a good answer.

Comment: I haven't been to the callmeicons.com website because I didn't trust it.  What I want to do should be done from the phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call a contact action is built in to shortcuts.

- https://support.apple.com/guide/shortcuts/welcome/ios

You can add shortcuts to Siri or the Home Screen. I think you need something like [Widgetsmith](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/widgetsmith/id1523682319) or [scriptable](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/scriptable/id1405459188) to convert a shortcut to Lock Screen widget but iOS 16 might have even more options when it ships.

You also should try adding your contact to their Home Screen - that way you can have the person’s face and other contact details ready for FaceTime, messages, etc…

Comment: I've accepted this as the answer, but felt that the comment Steve Chambers gave was also very useful.