# One-touch Facetime call on iPad

Tags: ipad, facetime

I am trying to setup Facetime on an iPad for a 93-year old senior who doesn't know how to navigate iPad apps.

I want her to touch an icon/picture on the iPad desktop and initiate a Facetime call to her daughter.

I have Facetime working but it doesn't start the call right away. Sometimes it ask questions and she was lost.

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

[Shortcuts app is the official way to do this.](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/443008/5472)

On iOS 15 you also might try adding a widget for that contact so your senior learner can interact with all things related to that contact as well.